# Sorting a list of Generics in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, generics

I'm trying to implement a sorting for Generics in Java. 
Here is the abstract class Function (T is my "key" in order to sort):

```
public abstract class Function<T extends Comparable<T>, S> {

    abstract public T compute(S o); 
}
```

Here is class Applier, whose method "apply" sorts the list according on the result of "compute":

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Applier<T extends Comparable<T>, S> {

    ArrayList<S> apply(ArrayList<S> input, Function<T, S> function) {
        ArrayList<T> output = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for(Iterator<S> it = input.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ){
            output.add(function.compute(it.next()));
        }
        T tmpTi, tmpTj; 
        S tmpSi, tmpSj; 
        for(int i=0; i<input.size(); i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<input.size(); j++) {
                if(output.get(i).compareTo(output.get(j))>0) {
                    tmpTi = output.get(i); 
                    tmpTj = output.get(j); 
                    output.remove(j); 
                    output.remove(i); 
                    output.add(i, tmpTi);
                    output.add(i, tmpTj);

                    tmpSi = input.get(i);
                    tmpSj = input.get(j);
                    input.remove(j);
                    input.remove(i);
                    input.add(i, tmpSj);
                    input.add(j, tmpSi);
                }
            }
        }
        return input; 
    }

}
```

My question is: is there a smarter way to do this sorting, maybe not with a bubblesort? 
Here is also the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Applier a = new Applier<>();
    StringLength strlen = new StringLength();

    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

    array.add("Hola");
    array.add("Man");
    array.add("randomstufff");
    array.add("Zerrone");
    array.add("Info3a");

    System.out.println("Order by length");
    System.out.print("before: ");
    System.out.println(array);
    a.apply(array, strlen); //works on original object
    System.out.print("After: ");
    System.out.println(array);
```

Comment: Is [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) smart enough?

Comment: in Java 8, you have `ArrayList.sort()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: Assuming you have Java8: `input.sort(Comparator.comparing(el -> function.compute(el)))`

Comment: Well that is assuming `function.compute()` is cheap. Because it will be called O(log(N)) times.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's an error in the way you swap elements in your Bubble Sort: When re-inserting the elements into `output`, you misplaced `i` and `j`. Also, instead of removing and re-inserting the elements, just use `set(index, element)` to overwrite the previous entry.

Also, instead of using two lists and keeping those lists in synch, better just use a `Map`.

```
public static class Applier<T extends Comparable<T>, S> {
    ArrayList<S> apply(ArrayList<S> input, Function<T, S> function) {
        Map<S, T> compareBy = new HashMap<>();
        for (S s : input) {
            compareBy.put(s, function.compute(s));
        }
        for(int i=0; i<input.size(); i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<input.size(); j++) {
                if (compareBy.get(input.get(i)).compareTo(compareBy.get(input.get(j))) > 0) {
                    S tmpS = input.get(j);
                    input.set(j, input.get(i));
                    input.set(i, tmpS);
                }
            }
        }
        return input; 
    }
}
```

And of course, sorting is already implemented in Java. So other than for learning how to code, you should always use the builtin functions. In Java 8, it's just a single line:

```
Collections.sort(array, Comparator.comparing(String::length));
```

Note, however, that `Comparator.comparing` will call the comparator function for each pairwise comparison (i.e. on the order of *2nlogn* times for a decent sorting algorithm). If that function is computationally *very* expensive, you might want to cache it yourself, using a `Map`.

```
Map<String, Integer> compareBy = array.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> s.length()));
Collections.sort(array, Comparator.comparing((String s) -> compareBy.get(s)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to sort an array based on some other array. You will be able to use `Collections.sort` if you introduce a wrapper object that contains both the values and the function results, and sort that one.

Here's a solution using Java 8 streaming API:

```
public class Applier<T extends Comparable<T>, S> {

    static class Wrapper<T extends Comparable<T>,S> implements Comparable<Wrapper<T,S>> {
        T key;
        S value;
        Wrapper(S s, Function<T, S> function) {
            this.key = function.compute(s);
            this.value = s;
        }
        public int compareTo(Wrapper<T,S> that) {
            return key.compareTo(that.key);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<S> apply(ArrayList<S> input, Function<T, S> function) {
        S[] sorted = (S[]) IntStream.range(0, input.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> new Wrapper<T,S>(input.get(i), function))
            .sorted()
            .map(b -> b.value).toArray();
        input.clear();
        input.addAll(Arrays.asList(sorted));
        return input;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! 
I think the second solution is more OO, but I don't really get the point of creating a static inner class, could you please clear my doubt?